# Убрать коллизии в массиве диапазона дат

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив периодов дат без учёта времени (для наглядности сделал даты в виде строк, но на самом деле timestamp'ы):

```
$items = [
['fromDate' => '2016-01-01', 'toDate' => '2016-01-12'],
['fromDate' => '2016-02-02', 'toDate' => '2016-02-12'],
['fromDate' => '2016-03-01', 'toDate' => '2016-03-01'],
['fromDate' => '2016-01-05', 'toDate' => '2016-01-16'],
// ...
];
```

**Вопрос**: как преобразовать $items так, чтобы слить коллизии среди дат?
Например, есть период `01.01.2016 — 10.01.2016` и `05.01.2016 — 12.01.2016`, то мы должны получить вместо двух элементов один — `01.01.2016 — 12.01.2016`.

Ещё пример: `01.03.2017 — 04.03.2017` и `05.03.2017 — 05.03.2017` в `01.03.2017 — 05.03.2017`.

После объединения, новый диапазон может быть также слит с другими элементами.
На выходе мы должны получить тот же массив $items только уже со слитыми коллизиями, если они есть.

Comment: написать алгоритм) сливка по номеру месяца?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Почему же? Целиком по дате. 01.03.2013-01.01.2014 и 02.01.2014-02.10.2014 тоже должны слиться.

Comment: напишите четкие правила сливки дат в одну, а то у вас в одном примере дата пересекается и сливается, в другом даты не пересекаются, но тоже сливаются.

Comment: @Jean-Claude всего 2 правила: 1. периоды пересекаются (частично или один поглощает другого); 2. периоды следуют друг за другом разрывом в день (один заканчивается 1-ого числа, второй начинается 2-ого)

Comment: я пробовал, но что-то мозгов не хватает если честно(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, благодаря вам, получилось и у самого:

```
    function mergeChunks($items)
    {
        $sorter = function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a['from'] == $b['from']) {
                return 0;
            }

            return $a['from'] < $b['from'] ? -1 : 1;
        };

        usort($items, $sorter);

        $sortBox = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($items) - 1; $i++) {
            $item1 = $items[$i];
            $item2 = $items[$i + 1];

            if (strtotime($item1['to']) >= strtotime($item2['from']) - 86400) {
                $item1['to'] = $item1['to'] >= $item2['to'] ? $item1['to'] : $item2['to'];
                $sortBox[] = $item1;
                $sortBox = array_merge($sortBox, array_slice($items, $i + 2));

                return mergeChunks($sortBox);
            } else {
                $sortBox[] = $item1;

                if ($i == count($items) - 2) {
                    $sortBox[] = $item2;
                }
            }
        }

        usort($sortBox, $sorter);

        return $sortBox;
    }

    $items = mergeChunks([
        ['from' => '2016-01-01', 'to' => '2016-01-05'],
        ['from' => '2016-01-06', 'to' => '2016-03-15'],
        ['from' => '2016-02-01', 'to' => '2016-02-15'],
        ['from' => '2016-07-02', 'to' => '2016-08-15'],
    ]);

    print_r($items);

    // Результат:
    // ['from' => '2016-01-01', 'to' => '2016-03-15'],
    // ['from' => '2016-07-02', 'to' => '2016-08-15'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a["from"] == $b["from"]) {
    if ($a["to"] == $b["to"]) {
      return 0;
      return ($a["to"] < $b["to"]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a["from"] < $b["from"]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}

if (count($items) == 0)
  return null;
usort($items, "cmp");
$res = array();
$curItem = $items[0];
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if ($curItem['to'] + 3600 * 24 /*1 day*/ >= $item['from'])
    $curItem['to'] = $item['to'];
  else {
    $res[] = $curItem;
    $curItem = $item;
  }
}
$res[] = $curItem;
return $res;
```

1. Сортируем исходный массив
2. Берем первый элемент массива
3. Если следующий элемент можно склеить с текущим - склеиваем
4. Иначе - добавляем текущий элемент в результирующий массив и берем следующий

Comment: Спасибо. Выглядит логично. Я совсем забыл про сортировку! Поэтому пришлось делать вложенные циклы и из-за этого и не получилось. Завтра утром проверю и поставлю галочку)

Comment: @GroZa Заработало?

Comment: В целом верно, но есть косяки. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем не считать и просто отсортировать по месяцам , выбирая min-max то так :

```
$struct = [];
$items = [
    ['fromDate' => '2016-01-01', 'toDate' => '2016-01-12'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-02-02', 'toDate' => '2016-02-12'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-03-01', 'toDate' => '2016-03-01'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-01-05', 'toDate' => '2016-01-16']
];
//объединим все даты в 1 массив
$dates = array_merge(array_column($items , 'fromDate') , array_column($items, 'toDate'));

//разложим все даты по месяцам
array_map(function($date)use(&$struct){
        $m = new DateTime($date);
        $struct[$m->format('m')][] = $date;
}, $dates);

//выбираем min max дату в месяце
$items = array_map(function($range){
        return [
            'fromDate' => min($range),'toDate' => max($range)
        ];
}, $struct);

print_r($items);
```

на выходе

```
   [01] => Array
        (
            [fromDate] => 2016-01-01
            [toDate] => 2016-01-16
        )

    [02] => Array
        (
            [fromDate] => 2016-02-02
            [toDate] => 2016-02-12
        )

    [03] => Array
        (
            [fromDate] => 2016-03-01
            [toDate] => 2016-03-01
        )
```

В связи с выясненными в диалоге условиями обновляю пост , теперь поглощается независимо от месяца, учитывается весь диапазон дат .

```
$items = [
    ['fromDate' => '2016-01-01', 'toDate' => '2016-01-12'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-02-02', 'toDate' => '2016-02-12'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-02-12', 'toDate' => '2016-02-22'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-03-01', 'toDate' => '2016-03-01'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-01-03', 'toDate' => '2016-01-10'],
    ['fromDate' => '2016-01-05', 'toDate' => '2016-01-16'],
    ['fromDate' => '2013-10-10', 'toDate' => '2013-12-13'],
    ['fromDate' => '2012-01-01', 'toDate' => '2015-03-10'],
];

$startDates = array_column($items , 'fromDate');
array_walk($items, function(&$item)use($startDates , &$items){

    //диапазон всех дат входящих в период 
    $end = new DateTime($item['toDate']);
    $period = new DatePeriod(
         new DateTime($item['fromDate']),
         new DateInterval('P1D'),
         $end->modify("+1 day"),
         DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
    );
    //итератор периода
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        $search = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        //ищем наличие пересечения, если оно есть удаляем диапазон из массива , 
        //если в удаляемом массиве конечная дата выше , обновляем ее
        $id = array_search($search , $startDates);
        if($id !== false){
            if($item['toDate'] < $items[$id]['toDate']){
                $item['toDate'] = $items[$id]['toDate'];
            }
            unset($items[$id]);

        }
    }   
});

print_r($items);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но по месяцам не подходит. Скажем, вот есть такой диапазон 10.10.2013-23.12.2013 и такой 01.01.2012-10.03.2015 и, логично, что второй должен поглотить первый.

Comment: Но оноже решает вашу задачу

Comment: Выше поправил ответ) недописал

Comment: Или же в одном месяце может быть 2-3 диапазона непересекающихся. А поиск максимальной даты и минимальной объеденит их. И вообще причем тут месяц? Диапазон может идти и на годы.

Comment: Ну да изначально вопрос поставлен не правильно, по вопросу непонятно , что ты  хочеш получить в итоге . Но по твоей логике у тебя в конце концов всегда будет только абсолютный минимум и максимум .  .

Comment: Ну почему. Ну вот 2 диапазона 10-10-2010—15-10-2010 и 20-10-2010—15-11-2010 они НЕ пересекаются и следовательно их оставляем как есть. Смысл поста вообще в том, у нас есть база отпусков сотрудников, но заносят её довольно криво и это не изменить. скажем взял человек месяц отпуска сплошной, а в базе вместо одной записи с 01 по 28, стоит 4 записи по 7 дней. Или вообще идёт наложение друг на друга (facepalm) Цель убрать избыточность.

Comment: Теперь понятно) , попробуя сейчас по другому написать , но что бы не дублить верхний ответ применю свое решение.

Comment: А диапазоны у Вас равные? кратные 7 и не больше 4 повторений , так? и все это по сути должно входить в общий диапазон ?

Comment: Нет. скажем отпуск может быть разбит на 5 дней в одном месяце и 18 в другом и 3 в третьем. Вообще хочется найти **общее** решение без подобных условий кратности и "не больше X". Вот есть список диапазонов. Пусть будет один длинной в год а другой в 1 день, а третий на 3 месяца. Объеденить бы те, что идут один за другим без перерыва или накладываются друг на друга. Без условностей) Я утром пытался, но что-то не получилось. Вариант товарища Anton Shchyrov более правдоподобен, но надо проверить завтра будет.

Comment: Учел все условия , добавил их в массив , работает)) , обновил пост

Comment: Обновил ответ..